# CSS - Multiple uses of class stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS style that I use for labels

```
#profile form label {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 21px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
   text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333;
   top: 318px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 273px;
   opacity: 0.9;
   left: 140px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
}
```

I have a main div called `profile` and I have a form which uses labels, but when I try to place multiple labels, they stack on top of each other. How can I space them apart?

Comment: Space them apart how? Left to right? Your position is absolute, that's why they are stacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're positioning all of the labels with `position: absolute` and `top: 318px`, `left: 140px`.  Assuming they are all direct children of the `<form>`, this will place them all in the exact same spot.

You should try a different approach to positioning the labels, maybe `position: relative`, or trying a more row column style approach.

Comment: I tried changing the position to relative but I cant position the labels properly. I want them to take on the properties of this class, I dont want to define a new class everytime. Is there a way to do this

Comment: I would suggest not using `position: relative` then.  Try to get the desired layout using child containers of `<form>`.  It's difficult to give suggestions when I don't know what the desired layout is, however.

Comment: I want them to be spaced horizontally, when I use relative they are underneath eachother vertically

Comment: You can use the property `display: inline-block` on containers so that they will not force other elements in the same parent to be on a new line.  Then you can space them with properties like `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position to relative

Comment: I did, they just stack underneath eachother. I want to space them wider apart

Answer (score 0):

Have you might want to try margin and/or padding to space them out. If you want them side by side perhaps float:left as well?